# What is the difference between TFT LCD interfaces?

Tags: lcd, tft, glcd

I am looking at driving a small TFT and have found that the driver chip supports various interface methods, however I can't see why I would choose one over another.

The options are:

1. i80
2. SPI
3. VSYNC
4. RGB

Can anyone describe the pros and cons of the different interfaces?

In my specific case I want to drive an [ILI9320](http://www.densitron.com/uploadedFiles/Displays/Support/ILI9320DS_V0.51.pdf) with a PIC32 via the Parallel Master Port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "i80" parallel interface is simple and fast, and can be driven by external memory interfaces on some microcontrollers. However, it's a wide parallel bus, and requires a lot of pins to drive.

SPI requires very few pins to drive, and is available as a hardware peripheral on many microcontrollers. It's slower than the parallel interface, though.

The VSYNC and RGB interfaces are mainly useful for displaying streaming video from live sources (e.g, in a camera). They aren't useful outside special situations.

Given that you're using a PIC32 with what sounds like a big parallel port, the i80 interface is probably ideal.